# jQuery - how to reference an element before it is loaded

Tags: jquery, ajax, element

I have "function 1" that references an element on success:

```
$('#element').show();
```

However, that element is loaded via ajax after "function 1" and the element does not show.

How can I tell jQuery that this element now exists and to be able to reference it?

Comment: You can't. You have to call this method when the element exists.

Comment: You could always just change your CSS to not hide `#element` in the first place ?

Comment: it needs to be hidden for 10seconds after loading :(

Comment: Add the `$('#element').show()` call _after_ adding the element. Can't you put that line in the Ajax success handler after it adds the element (along with code to delay for 10 seconds)?

Comment: Give us more context in which you `.show()` this element, e.g. the ajax success handler or so.

Answer (score 0):

jquery .on() can be used to refer to the DOM elements that would be added in the future

Comment: What you describe is called *event delegation*, but the OP's problem has nothing to do with events.